# Output for TikaBatch via tika-app-X.Y.jar

Tags: cygwin, text-processing, apache-tika, text-parsing, tika-server

I am trying to extract the text for a bunch of documents(.pdf, .doc, etc) present in an "Input" using (in cygwin)

```
java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar -t -i /Inputfolder -o /Outputfolder
```

The causeForTermination is "COMPLETED_NORMALLY" but I can't see any files in the output folder. What am I not specifying?

Comment: @NicomedesE. Do all the documents present in the input folder get parsed and appear in the output folder? That doesnt seem to be happening in my case

Comment: Rechecked! This command worked for me too! I guess I messed up the path of the folders.

Comment: @NicomedesE. I used this command in my R script with the system command and noticed that it stops abruptly with the causeForTermination being "USER_INTERRUPTION" and only a couple of files get parsed (I have about 20). When i rerun the script, the command parses some more files. To parse all the files, I have to run the command a few times instead of just once. Any idea how to tackle this?